# Assigning a single value to an array of a composite type by referencing a column name

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

Do you have any opinion?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_test()
   RETURNs integer
AS
$$
declare
   tb_var dba_reports[];
   v_serialno int := 1;
begin
   SELECT array_agg(tbl) into tb_var FROM "dba_reports" tbl;
   RAISE NOTICE '%', tb_var[v_serialno].report_id;
   tb_var[v_serialno].report_id :=99
   
   return 1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
> LINE 14:    tb_var[v_serialno].report_id :=99
> ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @serhad-erdem
Can you please add the table definition for dba_reports?